# Cannot connect to my local host port:3000 after i set up MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, terminal, database-connection

For some reason my code suddenly won't connect to my local host.  My...

`var app = require('../app');`

...will not connect.  I have tried a lot of different variations of this path too.  Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing incorrect?  The error messages my terminal is giving me is below as well.  This comes after I recently tried connecting MongoDB to my program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, I realize the terminal error says it cannot find path '/../', however this is just an example of one of the 20+ paths I tried.  The path that I was originally using, and I believe has always worked for me, is the path in my code '../app'.

Comment: what error do you get with `var app = require('../app');`, that one is the correct one.

Comment: Did you try ./app?

Comment: Yes I tried ./app.  Every time it gives me the same error which is above.